# Built in windows font wont load correctly in MonoGame

Tags: monogame, xml, xna-content-pipeline, spritefont

I am currently attempting to load this font in the MonoGame pipeline:
[image]

I set the .spriteFont file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
Modify this string to change the font that will be imported.
-->
<FontName>System</FontName>

<!--
Size is a float value, measured in points. Modify this value to change
the size of the font.
-->
<Size>12</Size>

<!--
Spacing is a float value, measured in pixels. Modify this value to change
the amount of spacing in between characters.
-->
<Spacing>0</Spacing>

<!--
UseKerning controls the layout of the font. If this value is true, kerning information
will be used when placing characters.
-->
<UseKerning>true</UseKerning>

<!--
Style controls the style of the font. Valid entries are "Regular", "Bold", "Italic",
and "Bold, Italic", and are case sensitive.
-->
<Style>Regular</Style>

<!--
If you uncomment this line, the default character will be substituted if you draw
or measure text that contains characters which were not included in the font.
-->
<!-- <DefaultCharacter>*</DefaultCharacter> -->

<!--
CharacterRegions control what letters are available in the font. Every
character from Start to End will be built and made available for drawing. The
default range is from 32, (ASCII space), to 126, ('~'), covering the basic Latin
character set. The characters are ordered according to the Unicode standard.
See the documentation for more information.
-->
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#32;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

It returned this (I am unable to obtain a text version of this): [image]

I also tried setting the .spritefont file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
Modify this string to change the font that will be imported.
-->
<FontName>System Bold</FontName>

<!--
Size is a float value, measured in points. Modify this value to change
the size of the font.
-->
<Size>12</Size>

<!--
Spacing is a float value, measured in pixels. Modify this value to change
the amount of spacing in between characters.
-->
<Spacing>0</Spacing>

<!--
UseKerning controls the layout of the font. If this value is true, kerning information
will be used when placing characters.
-->
<UseKerning>true</UseKerning>

<!--
Style controls the style of the font. Valid entries are "Regular", "Bold", "Italic",
and "Bold, Italic", and are case sensitive.
-->
<Style>Regular</Style>

<!--
If you uncomment this line, the default character will be substituted if you draw
or measure text that contains characters which were not included in the font.
-->
<!-- <DefaultCharacter>*</DefaultCharacter> -->

<!--
CharacterRegions control what letters are available in the font. Every
character from Start to End will be built and made available for drawing. The
default range is from 32, (ASCII space), to 126, ('~'), covering the basic Latin
character set. The characters are ordered according to the Unicode standard.
See the documentation for more information.
-->
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#32;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
Modify this string to change the font that will be imported.
-->
<FontName>System</FontName>

<!--
Size is a float value, measured in points. Modify this value to change
the size of the font.
-->
<Size>12</Size>

<!--
Spacing is a float value, measured in pixels. Modify this value to change
the amount of spacing in between characters.
-->
<Spacing>0</Spacing>

<!--
UseKerning controls the layout of the font. If this value is true, kerning information
will be used when placing characters.
-->
<UseKerning>true</UseKerning>

<!--
Style controls the style of the font. Valid entries are "Regular", "Bold", "Italic",
and "Bold, Italic", and are case sensitive.
-->
<Style>Bold</Style>

<!--
If you uncomment this line, the default character will be substituted if you draw
or measure text that contains characters which were not included in the font.
-->
<!-- <DefaultCharacter>*</DefaultCharacter> -->

<!--
CharacterRegions control what letters are available in the font. Every
character from Start to End will be built and made available for drawing. The
default range is from 32, (ASCII space), to 126, ('~'), covering the basic Latin
character set. The characters are ordered according to the Unicode standard.
See the documentation for more information.
-->
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#32;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

Both return the same error.

I need help in making this build correctly. I have looked on the web for a while and I could not find a solution.

Here is my entire pipeline window:
[image]